# Use StringLike instead of String in Scala?

Tags: scala, abstraction, strings, trait

Scala has the StringLike trait. Let's say I want to create a case class `Name` and internally it should save the name with some characters. Should I use `case class Name(name: StringLike)` or `case class Name(name: String)`?

The former is obviously more abstract. It means someone can give me `CustomString` that extends `StringLike` and he might overwrite some methods.

If I want to be sure the given argument behaves like the `String` class I know, I should use `String` and else `StringLike`. Is that correct? Are there cases in which it would make a practically difference?

Also, are there things I can do with the more specialized `String` that I can't do with a `StringLike`?

Answer (score 8):

Although it's usually good practice to accept as abstract of arguments as possible, in Scala you generally want to avoid directly using any types with `[Repr]` parameters.  They are mostly there for the convenience of the standard library implementors.

That's especially true for `StringLike`, which is primarily intended to augment a Java `String` to be able to also act like a collection of characters.  You're not  supposed to look at the man behind the curtain to see how that's accomplished.  Nor is it expected that anyone would ever make a custom `StringLike` implementation.

`String` is also much better from a simple readability standpoint.  If you need something that behaves like a `String`, just use a `String`.  In the extremely remote chance you ever need something kind of like a `String`, but not really, you can make the change then, and there may be a better solution.